# Filtering special character issue in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-filters

Here is my json and i wish to extract **listItem** value from below string json :-

```
$scope.field='{\n \"**listItem**\": \"svo.svo.svoMetadata.event\",\n \"position\": \"1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SS\"\n}';
```

This is how i am trying parsing on front-end using ng-value & angular's default json filter :

```
input type="text" ng-value="field.listItem | json" />
```

but can't extract `listItem` from json above, although I am able to extract field as whole string json.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's working :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  /* $scope.categories = [{
    name: "Category name"
    products: [
      0: "product name"
    ]
  }];*/
  
  $scope.field={"listItem": "svo.svo.svoMetadata.event","position": "1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SM.1$SS"};
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <input type="text" ng-model="field1" ng-value="field.listItem |json" />

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yeah , it would work but sadly i cant change json , its json coming from service and being visualised on ui , so please suggest other solution with my json.

Comment: It is just demo from your asked question, you can change json from service.

Comment: Thanks jigar but I have  a huge json that has this string value that I don't want to iterate and remove \n for just one key. and just to be clear by service is a REST service.